# How to display an detail disclosure button for the rows in an UITableView in plain style?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How to display an detail disclosure button for the rows in an UITableView in plain style? I want that when a row is tapped, the next level in the navigation is pushed on the navigation stack.

Is there a quick way to get this blue detail disclosure button in the cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Keep in mind that the detail disclosure button is supposed to invoke a different action than the action that is invoked by tapping the cell. You might want to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` instead. Read the Human Interface Guidelines for the difference between the two.